# How to take correct home address from user?

Tags: flutter

I am building an App using Flutter and I am asking user for their address. Currently I'm using normal form field to take data like city, zip code, state and Country so some users just enter anything in the field which even doesn't make sense like state name doesn't fall in that Country state list and same with the zip code and city.

I want to restrict user to enter correct data. For example if someone Enters Country USA only states that are in USA can only be entered. I don't know how to do that is there any packages or api available?

Answer (score 0):

Use Flutter Forms validation. It seems super-verbose but that's how Flutter does it.

Wrap your fields in a Form(). For each one you'll have an onChanged function, an onSaved function (probably) and then add a validator function for each field. That's the important part. The validator should return null if there's no problem with the data. It should return a string with a description of the error if there is a problem.

Here's a way-too-big code sample:

```
// <-- Add this widget. (Don't forget to close it!)
        autovalidate: _autovalidate, // <-- Add this line
        key: _key, // <-- Add this line
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildEmailField,
              _buildPasswordField,
              _buildPasswordConfirmationField,
              _buildAgreeToTermsField,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.save),
        onPressed: _doRegister,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _buildEmailField {
    return TextFormField(
      // TODO 4: Change to a TextFormField
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
      // TODO 5: Add onSaved and validator methods
      onSaved: (String val) => _loginObject['email'] = val,
      validator: _validateEmail,
      // TODO 9: Add autofocus
      autofocus: true,
      // TODO 10: Add a focusNode
      focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
    );
  }

  Widget get _buildPasswordField {
    return TextFormField(
      // TODO 4: Change to a TextFormField
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password"),
      obscureText: true,
      onChanged: (String val) => setState(() => _pass1 = val),
      // TODO 6: Add onSaved and validator methods to the password field
      onSaved: (String val) => _loginObject['password'] = val,
      validator: _validatePassword,
    );
  }

  Widget get _buildPasswordConfirmationField {
    return TextFormField(
      // TODO 4: Change to a TextFormField
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password (again)"),
      obscureText: true,
      // TODO 7: Validate the password confirmation here
      validator: _validatePasswordConfirmation,
    );
  }

  Widget get _buildAgreeToTermsField {
    // TODO 8: Wrap the Column with a FormField<bool>
    return FormField<bool>(
      // 1
      initialValue: _agree,
      builder: (FormFieldState<bool> state) {
        // 2
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Checkbox(
                  // 3
                  value: state.value,
                  onChanged: (bool val) => setState(() {
                    // 4
                    _agree = val;
                    // 5
                    state.didChange(val);
                  }),
                ),
                const Text("I agree to the terms."),
              ],
            ),
            // 6
            state.errorText == null
                ? Text("")
                : Text(state.errorText, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
          ],
        );
      },
      // 7
      validator: (val) => _validateTerms(_agree),
    );
  }

  // Valid if we get a well-formed and non-empty email address
  String _validateEmail(String email) {
    // 1
    RegExp regex = RegExp(r'\w+@\w+\.\w+');
    // Add the following line to set focus to the email field
    if (email.isEmpty || !regex.hasMatch(email)) _emailFocusNode.requestFocus();
    // 2
    if (email.isEmpty)
      return 'We need an email address';
    else if (!regex.hasMatch(email))
      // 3
      return "That doesn't look like an email address";
    else
      // 4
      return null;
  }

  String _validatePassword(String pass1) {
    RegExp hasUpper = RegExp(r'[A-Z]');
    RegExp hasLower = RegExp(r'[a-z]');
    RegExp hasDigit = RegExp(r'\d');
    RegExp hasPunct = RegExp(r'[_!@#\$&*~-]');
    if (!RegExp(r'.{8,}').hasMatch(pass1))
      return 'Passwords must have at least 8 characters';
    if (!hasUpper.hasMatch(pass1))
      return 'Passwords must have at least one uppercase character';
    if (!hasLower.hasMatch(pass1))
      return 'Passwords must have at least one lowercase character';
    if (!hasDigit.hasMatch(pass1))
      return 'Passwords must have at least one number';
    if (!hasPunct.hasMatch(pass1))
      return 'Passwords need at least one special character like !@#\$&*~-';
    return null;
  }

  String _validatePasswordConfirmation(String pass2) {
    return (pass2 == _pass1) ? null : "The two passwords must match";
    // Note that _pass1 is populated when a password is entered
  }

  String _validateTerms(bool agree) {
    return agree ? null : "You must agree before proceeding";
    // It's invalid if the user hasn't opted in by checking the box
  }

  void _doRegister() {
    // After the first attempt to save, turn on autovalidate to give quicker feedback to the user
    setState(() => _autovalidate = true); // <-- Add this line
    // TODO 3: Add validation and saving here
    if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
      // Commit the field values to their variables
      _key.currentState.save();
      print("""
      The user has registered with an email address of '${_loginObject['email']}' 
      and a password of '${_loginObject['password']}'
      """);
    }
  }
}
```